# Checking if pst file is password protected

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, pst

Is there a way to check if a microsoft outlook pst file is password protected or not using c#.
I'm trying to read the pst file using the below code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder emailFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124834/check-if-a-pst-file-is-password-protected-with-java-libpst

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a property in the api, as a work around you could query the contacts or email folder. If the pst file is protected, it shouldn't work.

```
MAPIFolder contacts = olMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)

foreach (ContactItem contact in fcontacts .Items)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: well if its password protected it will prompt for password.I just want to know if its password protected in order to avoid that password prompt